# jsPDF set table style

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf

How i can set height of table cell, i now using this code:

```
function createNew()
{
    //GenPDF();
    var doc = new jsPDF();          
    var elementHandler = {
      '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };
    var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    doc.fromHTML(
        source,
        15,
        15,
        {
          'width': 500,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
        });

    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
}
```

On page i have two words on header and more then 30 tables, but in pdf tables cell height is so big and use much space, can some one help me for add cell height in this code, or maybe have a some way for this in my html tables?

Answer (score -1):

i found a solution:

```
    function createNew() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter')
```

, source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]

, specialElementHandlers = {

```
'#CreateReport' : function(element, renderer){
    // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
    return true;
},

'#PrintReport': function(element, renderer){
    // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
    return true;
},

'#ignorePDF':   function(element, renderer){
    // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
    return true;
}
```

}

margins = {
  top: 60,
  bottom: 60,
  left: 40,
  width: 1000
 };

pdf.fromHTML(
    source
    , margins.left 
    , margins.top 
    , {
        'width': margins.width 
        , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },
    function (dispose) {
      pdf.output("dataurlnewwindow");
    },
    margins
)
}

i put this code and now working fine